# How to stop the application?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. In that in first view I place the one `UIswitch`. By using that switch we start the application. When that switch was start in that time only the application should work otherwise the application should not work. Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: First, the sentence *"By using that switch we start the application."* needs explanation as you can only use the switch if the app is already running, so the sentence doesn't seem to make sense. Then, what do you mean with that your application *"doesn't work"* when the switch is set ? Does it crash ? Does it not behave as you expect it ? If it crashes, what error do you get in the debug console ? In short: you need to provide a lot more description and data so we can help you.

Comment: Please explain more detailed what you're trying to do. From what I can understand after reading your post it doesn't seem to be appropriate for an iPhone app.

Comment: Isn't your application already started when you go to that first view..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple strongly suggests not to do this. I think an app with this "feature" wont pass the review process.

In case you still want to do this you can call `exit();`.

Another really bad approach is to access an index in an empty array.

Comment: "another really bad approach is to access an index in an empty array" where did you get that now?

Comment: ACK, deliberately crashing an app is very bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Place your switch in first View and don't navigate user to next(your actual application view), till switch is not set to on.